# Have to touchswipe twice to advance to next DIV using counter and modulus if statement

Tags: jquery, modulus

I have set up a simple snap to DIV structure using the jQuery TouchSwipe plugin. I have set up a basic counter to track how many times the user has swiped each DIV and I'm using the modulus operator in an if/else statement. Everything is working except for one small bug that I'm having trouble solving.

When I scroll back up to DIV one from DIV two, then directly back down to DIV two from DIV one I have to swipe two times. I know I need a more specific condition in my if statement but need a little help pinpointing what it should be. Thanks for any help and let me know if you need me to be any more specific.

Working demo is up here: http://dev.speakdesign.com/touchswipe/demos/myswipe_rev.html

Code is below:

HTML/JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <script id='code_1'>
                $(function() {          

                $("div.box").swipe( {
                    swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                        var count = this.data('count') ? this.data('count') + 1 : 1;
                        this.data('count', count);
                        if(count % 2) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
                            }, 200);
                        } else {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $(this).prev().offset().top
                            }, 200);
                        }
                    },

                    swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                        var count = this.data('count') ? this.data('count') + 1 : 1;
                        this.data('count', count);
                        if(count % 2) {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
                            }, 200);
                        } else {
                            $('html,body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
                            }, 200);
                        }
                    },
                    //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                    threshold:0
                });

            });
            </script>
            <div id="test">Intro Area</div>

            <div id="test" class="test box one">First Section</div>
            <div id="test" class="test box two">Second Section</div>
            <div id="test" class="test box three">Sixth Section</div>

            <div id="test">Footer Area</div>

        </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}

.container
{
    max-width:768px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box
{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    max-width:768px;
    height:300px;

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    text-align:center;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 36px;

    overflow:hidden;
}

body
{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333;
}

a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333; 
}

#test {
    height: 450px;
}

.three {
    margin-bottom: 600px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with TouchSwipe so forgive me if this is dumb, but what is data("count")? is the context the swipe event? Where is count set?

Comment: @isick I copied that code directly from one of the TouchSwipe demos. It is setting a count variable to track the number of times the user has swiped. I don't completely understand the data("count") part of the code but I assume that it is something that is needed to track the touch events. The plugin author may explain it more in the documentation. http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it was using modulus on the count to determine which div to scroll to, but I'm certain your problem has something to do with that.

Try this code:

```
        $(function() {          
            $("div.box").swipe( {
                swipeDown:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                    var scrollTarget = $(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top 
                                               ? $(this).offset().top 
                                               : $(this).prev().offset().top;
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: scrollTarget
                    }, 200);
                },

                swipeUp:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                    var scrollTarget = $(window).scrollTop() < $(this).offset().top 
                                               ? $(this).offset().top 
                                               : $(this).next().offset().top;
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: scrollTarget
                    }, 200);
                },
                //Default is 75px, set to 0 for demo so any distance triggers swipe
                threshold:0
            });

        });
```

The logic behind this is when you swipe up (you want to scroll down) so it checks what element the window is currently scrolled to. If the Scroll position is passed the current element then it scrolls you to the next one. If it's not passed this element then it scrolls to this one.

There is a potential edge case where if you swipe two elements down, it will scroll to that one effectively skipping one. If you want, I can re-write it to handle this condition, but I think this will for most scenarios.

Swiping down is obviously the same idea, but reversed.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working very well. The TouchSwipe plugin wasn't using modulus, I had set that up and was kind of stuck down that rabbit hole having trouble coming back. :) Your solution makes perfect sense.